# Perform some event on "Stop Operation

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I am looking to perform some function that take action on Stoping the Script

By clicking the [image]

Is that possible??

I am using .Net object and some of them must do Dispose to close them.
I want to know if there possible to do that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean here by "stopping the script".  Are you talking about errors?  Then take a look at `Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally -ShowWindow`.  If you're talking about hitting the break button in PowerShell ISE, I don't know of anything that would trigger off that.  It's the equivalent of hitting Ctrl-Break, which terminates the process.

Comment: So it sounds to me like you're using a loop with no exit, and you'd still like to act on whatever is happening in the loop when you decide it's time to exit?  Give us some more detail about exactly what you're trying to do and someone can help. Things that come to mind - declare first an empty collection $collection = @() and then $collection += (some stuff in the loop) and then, when you stop the script you should still be able to access the $collection.  Otherwise, instead of stopping the script manually, you could have it check for some condition, like a file you create when it should stop.

Comment: @ChrisN yea loop $true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to know if you can somehow trap the pressing of the Stop button (receipt of break signal). I don't know of a way, in powershell, to notice the break signal, but you can use a finally block to make sure that your Dispose code gets called. Here's my simple test:

```
try{
    while($true)
    {
        Write-Host "In try block . . . "
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
}
catch
{
       Write-Host "In catch block"
}
finally
{
       Write-Host "In finally block"
}
```

When I run it from the ISE and press the stop button (or press ctrl-C) I get:

```
# C:\Temp> .\stopEx.ps1
In try block . . . 
In try block . . . 
In finally block
```

Comment: That worked for me.

didnt know the finally worked on break; :)